# Neo4j Index Produce Error : Reference value not initialised at offset 0 When Running Queries

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Currently I need to implement index to property of my nodes(name and default) to nodes "A".
This nodes "A" is parent nodes of few nodes "B", "C", "D", "E", "F". 
In the java model "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" are the extends of nodes "A".
So the problem is after I implement the index for name and default to nodes "A". I suddenly got error like this :

```
2018-11-05 10:21:27.522 ERROR 3132 --- [io-8443-exec-11] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed"; Code: Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed; Description: Reference value not initialised at offset 0 in 
PrimitiveExecutionContext {
    SlotConfiguration(longs=3, refs=1, slots=Map(  label@1528 -> RefSlot(0,true,Any),   b@1458 -> LongSlot(1,false,Relationship),   a@1448 -> LongSlot(2,false,Node),   c@1462 -> LongSlot(0,false,Node)))
    LongSlot(0,false,Node)         '  c@1462' = Long(1771)
    LongSlot(1,false,Relationship) '  b@1458' = Long(5286)
    LongSlot(2,false,Node)         '  a@1448' = Long(1770)
    RefSlot(0,true,Any)            '  label@1528' = null
}
] with root cause
```

Any idea what's this error about ? I tried searching but no luck.
So far I only know that the graphId 1528 have something that is null but i don't know which one.

Notes: 
- I'm using Neo4j Enterprise Edition. The DB version is 3.4.6
- The A,B,C,D,E,F nodes isn't represented in the error since I don't know which one is which. But the general structure of the model is like that

Thank you

Comment: can you show your query?